# Make a dictionary of term frequency values

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a function that will take a list of words(strings), count how many times each specific word appears, and return a dictionary with the number of times the word appears in the list divided by the total number of words in the list (term frequency vector).

```
def makeTermFrequencyVector(wordList):
'''
makeTermFrequencyVector Takes a list of words as parameter and returns a dictionary representing the term frequency
vector of the word list, where words are keys and values are the frequency of occurrence of
each word in the document.
'''
tfDict = {}
for word in wordList:
    for i in range(len(wordList)):
        state = 0
        if wordList[i] == word:
            state += 1
    tfv = state / (len(wordList))
    tfDict[word] = tfv
return tfDict
```

If I inputted:

```
makeTermFrequencyVector(['cat', 'dog']):
```

the output should be:

```
{'cat': 0.5, 'dog': 0.5}
```

because each word appears once in a list of total length 2.

However, this code returns a dictionary with only the last word in the input list having the correct tf value, with all other words' values being 0.  So if I try to input the above list in my current code, it returns:

```
{'dog': 0.5, 'cat': 0.0}
```

which is not correct.

How can I fix this so it iterates the value over each word in the list and not just the last one?  I want to keep the fixed code as close to my current code as possible.

Comment: After the very first line of code, all the code should be indented, as it is inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler if we make separate passes instead of nested passes through the words.  On the first pass, we take of the word count.  On the second pass, we replace the word counts with frequencies:

```
def makeTermFrequencyVector(wordList):
    '''
    Takes a list of words and returns a dictionary representing
    the term frequency vector of the word list, where words are
    keys and values are the frequency of occurrence.
    '''

    tfDict = dict()

    for word in wordList:
        tfDict[word] = tfDict.get(word, 0) + 1

    word_count = len(wordList)

    for word in tfDict:
        tfDict[word] /= word_count

    return tfDict

print(makeTermFrequencyVector(['cat', 'dog']))

word_list = [ \
    'Takes', 'a', 'list', 'of', 'words', 'as', 'its', 'sole', 'parameter', \
    'and', 'returns', 'a', 'dictionary', 'representing', 'the', 'term', \
    'frequency', 'vector', 'of', 'the', 'word', 'list,', 'where', 'words', \
    'are', 'keys', 'and', 'values', 'are', 'the', 'frequency', 'of', \
    'occurrence', 'of', 'each', 'word', 'in', 'the', 'source', 'document', \
]

print(makeTermFrequencyVector(word_list))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
{'cat': 0.5, 'dog': 0.5}
{'Takes': 0.025, 'a': 0.05, 'list': 0.025, 'of': 0.1, 'words': 0.05, 'as': 0.025, 'its': 0.025, 'sole': 0.025, 'parameter': 0.025, 'and': 0.05, 'returns': 0.025, 'dictionary': 0.025, 'representing': 0.025, 'the': 0.1, 'term': 0.025, 'frequency': 0.05, 'vector': 0.025, 'word': 0.05, 'list,': 0.025, 'where': 0.025, 'are': 0.05, 'keys': 0.025, 'values': 0.025, 'occurrence': 0.025, 'each': 0.025, 'in': 0.025, 'source': 0.025, 'document': 0.025}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

cdlane's use of a 2 pass approach is the way to go vs using nested for loops. The reason is that each pass will take O(n) time, where n is the length of the list. With two passes it'll be O(n) + O(n) = O(2n) time, but the constants are dropped to make an O(n) asymptotic run time.

Part of the reason your code isn't working is because `state` is placed in the inner loop, so with each iteration of that loop, state is reset to 0, rather than simply being incremented each time. If you take the line `state = 0` and bump it out of the inner for loop, I think the logic should then work.